# How to change the pointing location of gmap

Tags: php, html, google-maps

I'm a beginner.This is code for pointing London but I need to point the current location and point the specific location in another map.

head section

```
     <script>
     var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850);

     function initialize()
      {
       var mapProp = {
       center:myCenter,
       zoom:5,
       mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };

      var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

       var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
       position:myCenter,
        });

       marker.setMap(map);

         var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content:"Hello World!"
         });

        infowindow.open(map,marker);
       }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
      </script>
```

body section

```
      <div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Go on google maps And search for your exact adress. than at the bottom click on setting and share. You will see a sharing link like

https://www.google.com/maps/@51.5432695,-0.00187,15z

here you can get longtitude = 51.5432695 and latitude = -0.00187,15z

Replace with :

`var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(51.5432695,-0.00187,15z);`

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geolocation) for an example of using the browser's geolocation functionality

Answer (score 1):

Change the Longitude and Latitude in

```
var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850);
```

to the coordinates you need.

Answer (score 1):

**Try the below:**

```
var newyork = new google.maps.LatLng(40.69847032728747, -73.9514422416687);
```

you can update the latitue, longitude as per your requirement!!